# system.file() goes well, but base::system.file() not

Tags: r

Now, I develop some R package, to avoid double names between different packages, 
I want to use `base::system.file()`,

But once I run `base::system.file()` in my package, named `"aa"`,
 the first time is well, 
 but the second running, it return `""`, that is empty.

By eliminating `base`, that is `system.file()` goes well. Please let me know why return value  is `""` (empty).

```
 base::system.file("extdata", "aaaaa.stan", package="aa")
[1] ""
> system.file("extdata", "aaaaa.stan", package="aa")
[1] "C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/aa/inst/extdata/aaaaa.stan"
```

Comment: have you used `devtools::load_all()` ? In order for `base::system.file()` to work, you have to have actually installed the package.

Comment: Yes. I run `devtools::load_all(".")`.

Comment: So @CarlosSantillan's answer is right.  Everything will work fine if you (or an end user) actually installs the package.

Comment: Thank your for @Ben and @Carlos, I am not sure what should I do. Now I think, combining the reply of  @Ben and @Carlos, I can use weak version `system.file()`, (instead of strong version `base::system.file()` in my pacage, Is it O.K.? I am wrong?  Anyway, I am very happy for your kind reply. Thank you for @Ben and @Carlos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ?? to see which packages implement the function, 
devtools overwrites the system.file so it could be that system.file is different function than base:system.file

```
??system.file
```

also if you type  just the function it should display the package of the function

```
> base::system.file
function (..., package = "base", lib.loc = NULL, mustWork = FALSE) 
{
    if (nargs() == 0L) 
        return(file.path(.Library, "base"))
    if (length(package) != 1L) 
        stop("'package' must be of length 1")
    packagePath <- find.package(package, lib.loc, quiet = TRUE)
    ans <- if (length(packagePath)) {
        FILES <- file.path(packagePath, ...)
        present <- file.exists(FILES)
        if (any(present)) 
            FILES[present]
        else ""
    }
    else ""
    if (mustWork && identical(ans, "")) 
        stop("no file found")
    ans
}
<bytecode: 0x2342e00>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

it seems that system.file is running devtools:system.file which is different that base::system.file

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.6/topics/system.file

One is returning the path relative to the package

> When system.file is called from the R console (the global
>   envrironment), this function detects if the target package was loaded
>   with load_all, and if so, it uses a customized method of searching for
>   the file. This is necessary because the directory structure of a
>   source package is different from the directory structure of an
>   installed package.

Comment: following this idea - try `find("system.file")`

Comment: The output of ` base::system.file` is same as above except the `<bitecode:........>.     The result of `??system.file` is  [[[[ 
`devtools::system.file  Replacement version of system.file ` ]]]] and [[[`base::system.file  Find Names of R System Files`]]]].

Comment: The output of the code`find("system.file")` is the following:
`[1] "devtools_shims" "package:base"` .

Comment: Thank you for qick reply. I am very confused. To run my package without any error, it needs to drop the `base` from `base::system.file` and write `system.file("extdata", "aaaaa.stan", package="aa")`, and I am not sure that what package' system.file()  is running.